# Conditionally select a row every month - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, `tblTRX` that looks like this:

```
| Person | Counter | Transaction |   Tdate   | Ttype | Inventory |
|:------:|:-------:|:-----------:|:---------:|:-----:|:---------:|
|  Bill  |    D    |      -4     |  1/1/2019 |  SALE |     99    |
|  Bill  |    DA   |      -3     | 1/15/2019 |  SALE |     96    |
|  Susan |    DA   |      -3     | 1/21/2019 |  SALE |     93    |
|  Bill  |    AA   |      -2     | 2/22/2019 |  SALE |     91    |
| George |    AC   |      -2     |  3/4/2019 |  EMP  |     89    |
|  Susan |    AC   |      -2     |  3/5/2019 |  SALE |     87    |
|  Susan |    AA   |      -1     |  3/6/2019 |  SALE |     86    |
|  Susan |    D    |      -2     |  3/7/2019 |  SALE |     84    |
|  Susan |    AA   |      -4     |  3/8/2019 |  SALE |     80    |
|  Susan |    AB   |      -4     |  3/9/2019 |  SALE |     76    |
|  Susan |    AC   |      -4     | 3/10/2019 |  EMP  |     72    |
|  Susan |    D    |      -4     |  4/6/2019 |  SALE |     68    |
|  Susan |    D    |      -3     |  5/1/2019 |  SALE |     65    |
|  Susan |    AB   |      -3     |  5/9/2019 |  SALE |     62    |
| George |    DA   |      -1     | 5/22/2019 |  SALE |     61    |
| George |    AA   |      -4     | 5/23/2019 |  SALE |     57    |
| George |    DA   |      -3     | 6/11/2019 |  EMP  |     54    |
|  Bill  |    AA   |      -3     | 6/19/2019 |  EMP  |     51    |
| George |    AC   |      -4     | 6/20/2019 |  SALE |     47    |
|  Susan |    AB   |      -2     | 6/21/2019 |  SALE |     45    |
|  Bill  |    D    |      -4     |  7/2/2019 |  SALE |     41    |
|  Bill  |    DA   |      -4     |  7/3/2019 |  SALE |     37    |
| George |    D    |      -4     |  7/4/2019 |  EMP  |     33    |
|  Bill  |    AB   |      -1     |  8/2/2019 |  SALE |     32    |
|  Bill  |    AC   |      -2     | 9/20/2019 |  SALE |     30    |
|  Susan |    D    |      -3     | 9/23/2019 |  EMP  |     27    |
```

What I would like to do is, every month, add in the attrition rate for each employee. They are held in a table, `tblATTR`, that looks like this:

```
|  Employee  |  AttrRate |
|:----------:|:---------:|
| Bill       |  -5       |
| George     |  2        |
|  Susan     | -10       |
```

> Once a month, I need the attrition rate for each employee, added as a transaction into `tblTRX`.

The goal result would look like:

```
| Person | Counter | Transaction |   Tdate   | Ttype | Inventory |
|:------:|:-------:|:-----------:|:---------:|:-----:|:---------:|
|  Bill  |    D    |      -4     |  1/1/2019 |  SALE |     99    |
|  Bill  |   NULL  |      -5     |  1/1/2019 |  ATTR |     94    |
| George |   NULL  |      2      |  1/1/2019 |  ATTR |     96    |
|  Susan |   NULL  |     -10     |  1/1/2019 |  ATTR |     86    |
| George |    DA   |      -3     | 1/15/2019 |  SALE |     83    |
|  Susan |    DA   |      -3     | 1/21/2019 |  SALE |     80    |
|  Bill  |   NULL  |      -5     |  2/1/2019 |  ATTR |     75    |
| George |   NULL  |      2      |  2/1/2019 |  ATTR |     77    |
|  Susan |   NULL  |     -10     |  2/1/2019 |  ATTR |     67    |
|  Bill  |    AA   |      -2     | 2/22/2019 |  SALE |     78    |
|  Bill  |   NULL  |      -5     |  3/1/2019 |  ATTR |     73    |
| George |   NULL  |      2      |  3/1/2019 |  ATTR |     75    |
|  Susan |   NULL  |     -10     |  3/1/2019 |  ATTR |     65    |
| George |    AC   |      -2     |  3/4/2019 |  EMP  |     63    |
|  Susan |    AC   |      -2     |  3/5/2019 |  SALE |     61    |
|  Susan |    AA   |      -1     |  3/6/2019 |  SALE |     60    |
|  Susan |    D    |      -2     |  3/7/2019 |  SALE |     58    |
|  Susan |    AA   |      -4     |  3/8/2019 |  SALE |     54    |
|  Susan |    AB   |      -4     |  3/9/2019 |  SALE |     50    |
|  Susan |    AC   |      -4     | 3/10/2019 |  EMP  |     46    |
|  etc…  |         |             |           |       |           |
```

If you look at my post history, I normally try and post questions with honest code segments. I do not even know how to attempt this.

How can I accomplish the desired result? Which is periodically inserting a row every 30 days. I figured some pseudocode would look like:

```
for each MONTH in tblTRX:
    on month/01/year, insert attrition rates for each employee
    recalculate inventory
```

I know I can use the `SUM` function with a `ROW_NUMBER()` call to continue to sum the inventory from the current transaction and the inventory from the row before, so that is not as much of a concern as periodically inserting a row into the table data stream.

Comment: how often are you planning on actually *executing* this query? Only once, or once a month, or what?

Comment: If you're only asking how to do it monthly, then I think you need to look at your favorite reliable scheduler.  SQL Server Agent is typically used to execute things on a schedule.  I have also used Task Scheduler calling a .cmd script file using command line sqlcmd.

Comment: Probably daily. Sometimes transactions file in late (i.e., a postprocess), also new ones occur every day. The TLDR is that this will serve as the basis for a stochastic inventory model, and to do so, we want to "forecast" parts missing due to employee error, so we are assuming that every month, there is an X change to inventory for each employee.

Comment: I'm looking more at a SQL statement to be able to do this. Somehow, in a `SELECT` statement, I want to be able to run through this dataset and for every month, add in the example line (or set of lines) above. I imagine this is possible with some trigger (trigger being when the month changes), but not sure how to accomplish that, and can't find any reference material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
INSERT INTO tblTRX (Person, [Transaction], Tdate, Ttype)
SELECT B.Employee, B.AttrRate, CONCAT(M,'/1/',Y) , 'ATTR' 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(Tdate) Y, MONTH(TDate) M  FROM tblTRX) AS A 
    CROSS JOIN tblATTR B
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM tblTRX X WHERE X.Person = B.Employee AND X.Ttype = 'ATTR' AND X.Tdate = CONCAT(M,'/1/',Y) );

WITH CTE AS
(SELECT 
        *, FIRST_VALUE(Inventory) OVER(ORDER BY TDate, ID) 
          - FIRST_VALUE([Transaction]) OVER(ORDER BY TDate, ID) 
          + SUM([Transaction]) OVER(ORDER BY TDate, ID) as NewInventory
 FROM tblTRX )
UPDATE CTE set Inventory = NewInventory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the idea from below code, can't be tested, and need adjustment for sure.
The query gets the attr records, better to save some results to temp tables.

```
    -- Get the last Attr month for each user, 
    ;WITH cteA
    AS
    (
      SELECT Person,MAX(Tdate) AS LastAttrDate
      FROM tblTRX
      WHERE tType=N'ATTR'
      GROUP BY Person
    ),
   -- first and last transaction for each user
    cteT
    AS
    (
      SELECT Person,CONVERT(DATE,LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(30),MAX(Tdate),120),7)+N'-01'),120) AS LastTrxDate,
        CONVERT(DATE,LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(30),MIN(Tdate),120),7)+N'-01'),120) AS FirstTrxDate
      FROM tblTRX
      WHERE tType<>N'ATTR'
      GROUP BY Person
    ),
    -- calculate the month range to insert
    cteM
    AS
    (
      SELECT T.Person, CASE WHEN A.LastAttrDate IS NULL TEHN T.FirstTrxDate ELSE DATEADD(MONTH,1,A.LastAttrDate) AS StartMonth,
        T.LastTrxDate AS EndMonth
      FROM cteA A
      RIGHT JOIN cteT T
      ON A.Person=T.Person
    ),
    -- recursively generates the months
    cteAM
    (
      SELECT Person,StartMonth,DATEADD(Month,1,StartMonth) AS EndMonth, EndMonth AS LastTrxMonth
      FROM cteM
      WHERE EndMonth>=StartMonth
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Person,DATEADD(Month,1,StartMonth),DATEADD(Month,1,EndMonth),LastTrxMonth
      FROM cteAM
      WHERE LastTrxMonth>=StartMonth
    ),
    -- the inventory to do the cal
    cteIn
    (
      SELECT A.Person,MIN(T.Tdate) AS InvDate
      FROM tbTRX T
      INNER JOIN cteAM A
      ON T.Person=A.Person
      AND T.TDate >=A.StartMonth
      AND T.TDate<A.EndMonth
      GROUP BY A.Person
    )

    SELECT A.Person,NULL AS Counter, A.Attr AS Transaction, M.StartMonth AS TDate, 'ATTR' AS Ttype, T.Inventory + A.Attr AS Inventory
    FROM tbTRX T
    INNER JOIN cteIn I ON T.Person=I.Person AND T.TDate=I.InvDate
    INNER JOIN tblATTR A ON A.Person=I.Person
    INNER JOIN cteAM M ON M.Person=A.Person
```